# How do I set Vim's 'path' if a file's parent path tree is cookbooks/foo/recipes?

Tags: vim, chef-infra

I'm using MacVim to edit Chef cookbooks and I'd really like the `gf` (Go to file) command to open other Chef recipes in the same cookbook.

Super extra bonus points if your solution can open recipes in other Chef cookbooks as well.

So given a directory structure like this:

```
1. cookbooks/mycookbook/recipes/default.rb
2. cookbooks/mycookbook/recipes/foo.rb
3. cookbooks/mycookbook/recipes/bar.rb
4. cookbooks/apache2/recipes/default.rb
5. cookbooks/apache2/recipes/mod-ssl.rb
```

And `mycookbook/recipes/default.rb` contains this:

```
include_recipe 'mycookbook::foo'
include_recipe 'mycookbook::bar'
include_recipe 'apache2'
include_recipe 'apache2::mod_ssl'
```

I'd like Vim's `gf` command to be able to open the recipes listed above.

### Approach:

Basically, I'm thinking about using setlocal for Ruby files to set the `path` variable if the current Ruby file's parent directory structure is like `cookbooks/<cookbook name>/recipes/`, but I'm not sure how to do it.

For the easy solution, you could just add the current file's parent directory (recipes) to the `path` if the current file's parent path was `cookbooks/<cookbook name>/recipes/`.

For the more comprehensive solution, you would also need to add `cookbooks/<all cookbooks>/recipes/` to the `path` variable.

Comment: Well, what did you come up with?

Comment: I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: No, you should show us what you already tried. This place is not for having things done for you. You are expected to do some actual work before asking.

Comment: Do you want to search for file in that path or you want to browse the files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after several hours of reading Vim docs and Googling, I came up with this autocmd (broken into two lines for readability:

```
" Make gf work on Chef include_recipe lines
" Add all cookbooks/*/recipe dirs to Vim's path variable
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile */cookbooks/*/recipes/*.rb 
   \ setlocal path+=recipes;/cookbooks/**1
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be cool if you could do the same thing for templates?  For example:

```
template "/etc/sudoers" do
  source "sudoers.erb"
end
```

gf on sudoers.erb and it will pull up the sudoers template, and if more than one exists pull them up in a split window!